# Why do people use 115200 instead of 9600?

Tags: serial, serial-data

So I came across lots of Arduino program setting serial speed to 115200 instead of 9600, while many people just kept using 9600 for the same purpose.

Why did people choose to use 115200 or other available speed? Why not just use 9600?

Comment: Because they want to communicate faster, or because the other end point is setup to 115200, and they don't want to change it. Or They use UART for MIDI with 31250 baud.

Comment: Because choice. 115200 is faster than 9600.

Comment: I sometimes use 460800 because it does slow down the sketch less then 115200 baud. and to communicate with esp8266 AT firmware over hardware serial on Mega I use 500 000 baud, to read the data from WiFi as fast as possible

Comment: @Juraj Do you know the reason why 460800 makes it less slowing down? related to multiplication values maybe?)

Comment: @MichelKeijzers, the TX buffer is 63 bytes long. if it fills, write/print blocks. so the baud rate is 'reflected' to the sketch. if I want to see the debug messages, but the problem is timing related, then sometimes higher baud rate helps

Comment: @Juraj Ah ok, thought it was some 'magic' number.

Comment: I didn't make a complete table on highest baud rate over different USB chips, but 921600 baud didn't work when I tried

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Exactly, why not using a faster speed like Juraj suggested? You see, you just contradicted your sentence.

Comment: @Juraj / ShoutOutAndCalculate ... I understand that higher is better, but just wonder what the value came from.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers Commonly you can't choose the serial speed to be any number. There are "standard" speeds like [9600 and 115200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Settings) that all derived from the first standard speeds like 75. BTW, the speed has the unit "steps per second", and in case of serial transmission one step is one bit. All these standard speeds are integer multiples of 75, most of them by factors of 2. For example: 9600 = 2^7 * 75, 115200 = 3 * 2^9 * 75.

Comment: @busybee thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/softwareSerial Because 115200 band was also the fastest communication enabled by the software serial.